# Domain creation on windows machine via IIS

Tags: iis, dns, localhost, port

I wanted to create and map a domain(ex: site1.domain1.com) locally to the server running on localhost with some port, I've been trying to do via IIS, but raising port conflict issue, unable to create and start site domain while web server is up since the port is already occupied and vice versa.

Could you please provide how to resolve this or any other simple way to create and map the domain with the server running on localhost.

Comment: What have you done via IIS? Can you describe it more detailed?

Comment: Thanks for the response,
I've followed the instructions provided in https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8d44fb/how-to-access-the-site-using-domain-name-instead-of-localhos/
But when I try to map a domain to localhost with port in IIS and restart the service under Manage Website section on right, I'm getting port conflict error since a server is already running on the given port.
Let me know if you need more details, Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: You can use command "netstat -ano -p tcp" to check which PID is using the port. Then find the work process in task manager according to the PID. Another thing is if you try to change other ports and of other ports work well? Usually, port conflict can be solved by change other ports or close the work process which occupied the port.